# Parsing 2 json objects and put it under <td>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have 2 json objects which contains data and I want to parse them simultaneously and the data of those objects will be displayed in a table. Both of my json contains different data but got same keys. Example below

```
Object 1
    [
      {"eventCategory":"Button","totalEvents":11.0},
      {"eventCategory":"Contact","totalEvents":787.0},
    ]

Object 2
    [
      {"eventCategory":"Button","totalEvents":253.0},
      {"eventCategory":"Contact","totalEvents":512.0},
    ]
```

And I want to display this as below

```
<tr>
    <td>data from first object- Total events 11 </td>
    <td>data from second object - Total events 253 </td>
</tr>
```

How Can I achieve this in ruby? I  know I can club both objects and create a third object but do we have any better solution to that?
I have tried to iterate both objects in one loop like below

```
JSON.parse(@object1, @object2).each do |data|
```

but no success. Any help appreciated.

Comment: `[JSON.parse(@object1), JSON.parse(@object2)].flatten.each do ...`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev flatten is combining my two objects but as you can see in both of the objects my keys are same how can I depict which key value is of which object if I loop through it ?

Answer (score 1):

What is your question about? Just iterate object that you receive after json parse, try to debug it, get all information that you need and then output it on page with <\tr> and <\td> tags.

from the ruby documentation

```
parse(source, opts = {})
```

Parse the JSON document source into a Ruby data structure and return it. So you can send to this method only one data param and options hash. So, yes, you need to wrap two objects in one and then parse them.

Comment: I can't wrap two objects to 1 as I have similar keys. I have to display the values from both the objects as explained in the example above of <td> 1 object- Total events 11 </td>
    <td>2 second object - Total events 253 </td>

Comment: then use something like 
[@obj1, obj2].each do |obj|
data = Json.parse(obj)
#and then puts it or paste into template

Comment: Could you please give me an example for this. Iterating 2 objects

Comment: can I use the zip method for the same?

Comment: @ArihantGodha i think yes, you can

Answer (score 1):

```
    require 'json'
    data1 = '{ 
        "Object1" :[
          {"eventCategory":"Button","totalEvents":11.0},
          {"eventCategory":"Contact","totalEvents":787.0}
        ] 
        }'
     data2 = '{ 
        "Object2" :[
          {"eventCategory":"Button","totalEvents":253.0},
          {"eventCategory":"Contact","totalEvents":512.0}
        ] 
        }'   


     merged_hash = JSON.parse(data1).merge(JSON.parse(data2))


    Now parse the merged_hash to get the desired output

merged_hash.each do |x,y|
if x == "Object1"
    y.each do |p,q|
        puts p["eventCategory"] + ":" + p["totalEvents"].to_s
    end
elsif x == "Object2"
    y.each do |p,q|
        puts p["eventCategory"] + ":" + p["totalEvents"].to_s
    end 
end

end
```